# Custom top logo for Azure AD app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am developing a Azure AD app and would like to customize the AAD login screen for our app. Is it possible to have a custom logo (at the top of login box) per app? This is typically the page with login.microsoft.online in the url.

I noticed there is a website for this kind of configuration, but I think this is for the entire organization.

aad.portal.azure.com

I have 2 apps: app1.contoso.com and app2.contoso.com. I want a different banner for both. Not sure how this can be achieved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD only support to add **company branding** to your sign-in page in Azure AD at present. If you want it support to customize for the different apps, you may submit the feedback from [this link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/search?oauth_consumer_key=GXzk8Xs15zfBxRjoH2Jgzg&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1).